# React + FileInput send value

Tags: reactjs

How can i do next?

```
let files = e.target.files;
 this.state.file = files;


<input type="file" value={this.state.file} name="excel" style={{display: 'none'}}/>
```

I wish add file to input, and send this form after, but this not work.

Comment: Do you need to control the state of the file input with react?
Or you just want to send the file to the server?

Comment: @JulienKlepatch im do previw file with js-xlsx. And yeap, i dont modify him, avter preview i need send him

Comment: I would probably not try to control the input element itself (its state is already controlled by the browser), but you can still react to its internal state changes by binding an event handler: `onChange={myEventHandler}`